# How do I automatically see incoming commits in Intellij IDEA with git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We just switched from svn to git. The svn plugin in idea has this very nice feature to automatically check the repository for incoming commits every x minutes.

In the idea git plugin, I didn't find this feature - is this possible somehow to check my origin for new commits automatically and list them in the log?

(Would it make sense to automatically fetch the origin every x minutes with some automated workflow somehow?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check gittoolbox from jetbrain

[Gittoolbox](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox)

Comment: Great, that's excactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To update your local machine with commits from the remote repo, you can run `git fetch` from the command line. Equivalently, in IntelliJ, you can push Ctrl-Shift-A and type "fetch" then press Enter. I do not know how to set up IntelliJ to fetch automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Ctrl-Shift-A yet.

Comment: In this case, "Fetch" is available in some menu somewhere. I rarely use the menu at all since Ctrl-Shift-A allows me to search for any command or setting.